# Character Count (I do not know what to do next)

Tags: c, string

Okay so I got this activity to do and its called string concerto. I got the number 1 (reversing a string and turn vowels into an asterisk) but I cant answer number 2 its called character count.

Its like this:

```
Sample Run:
Enter string:   Mississippi
3
ssp

Enter string:   Committee
3
mte

Enter string:   mmmmrrnzzz
4
mmrz
```

I do not know what to do next with my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int count;
    printf("Input a word: ");
    gets(str);
    printf("Count: ");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    for (str ; str <= count ; str++)
    {
        blank space(dunno what to do)
    }
    printf("%s",str[count]);
    getch();
}
```

What should I do? Should I use a string command?(I really don't know those things because the prof didn't haven't discussed it really good and she discussed arrays more.)

Im on 1st yr college so we use c language and a new member here in stackoverflow so if I have any violations in this question please tell me about it so I can improve in asking here too and not being a nuisance in this website.

Comment: No no ... first you have to fix it! `gets()` is deprecated and actually was removed from the c standard. Use `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)` instead.

Comment: No, `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)`. Also, `scanf()` returns a value, check it. Don't you have any ideas? Involving arrays perhaps?

Comment: Mixing chalk with cheese here: `for (str ; str <= count ; str++)` because `str` isn't something you can alter, or compare with `int`.

Comment: Im really bad at arrays too its really confusing for me.

Comment: Er.. um.. search for examples about reversing strings? Plenty of SO questions about that.

Comment: And also, I don't understand ... You want to count the ocurrences of each character?

Comment: I got number 1 already.

Comment: `mmmmrrnzzz 4 mmrz` What does means `4`? if is because of the presence of 4M like `mmmm`, then what is `rz` in this story. Please edit your question

Comment: I really dont know what you're talkin about Sir its just I am new to this language and I dont get how should I answer the program question.

Comment: @Kenney NO, i don't think he need the length of that string, he need to count letters which are repeating it self, or something like that.

Comment: @PatrickVillanueva If you do not know what you exactly wont to do, how we can help you then ?

Comment: @PatrickVillanueva You need to explain what the program is supposed to do. We can't tell just from the name "character count". And we don't care about the other problems, take them out of the question.

Comment: @PatrickVillanueva i think i understand your program logic. Ḿississipi` there are 2 `ss` + another 2 `ss` and + another 2 `pp` and you print `ssp` because are repeating itself.

Comment: Ohh sorry about that... I will try to understand it better than I did before.

Comment: I get it now the count you input is like finding for letters that repeats itself or double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Question/comments, probably this should be what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[100] = "Mississippi";
    int i, found = 0;

    for(i = 1; str[i] != '\0';i++){
        if(str[i-1] == str[i]){
            found = i-1;
            found++;
            while(1){
                if(str[found] == str[found+1]){
                    found++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            printf("%c", str[i]);
            i = found;
        }
    }

    if(found == 0){
        printf("No repeated character was Found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ssp

Comment: I kind of get it but can I ask? What is the purpose of i-1 and found +1? I wanted to know what is its function so I can use it for the future activities like this.

Comment: Because you need to check the last position with the actual one. If you do `if(str[i] == str[i])` you will get `isisipi` and this is not what you need.

Comment: Same thing for `found = i-1;` remove that line and you will get `sssspp`